# R session hangs up after using ggplotly()

Tags: r, plotly, tsclust

My R session (within RStudio) hangs up after using ggplotly().
For testing, I use one of the examples of ?ggplotly. The example normally works ok once or twice, but the R session hangs up after several tries (in the example below, the 2nd run hung up the session). I cannot even close the RStudio from the GUI and have to use the System Monitor application to kill it.
This problem arises when I run the following code after I have loaded a given project, not
if I start a R session with no project. But the project does not load any data or package, so do not know how to identify the problem.
This is what I specifically do:

I have found that loading package TSclust is the problem:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)

    data(canada.cities, package = "maps")
    viz <- ggplot(canada.cities, aes(long, lat)) +
    borders(regions = "canada") +
    coord_equal() +
    geom_point(aes(text = name, size = pop), colour = "red", alpha = 1/2)
    ggplotly(viz, tooltip = c("text", "size"))
    #check that works
    #clear all Viewer panes with the button
    require(TSclust)
    ggplotly(viz, tooltip = c("text", "size"))
    #no View and R hangs up



> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] TSclust_1.3.1 cluster_2.1.2 pdc_1.0.3     plotly_4.10.3 ggplot2_3.4.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rgl_1.2.1              Rcpp_1.0.11            lattice_0.20-45        tidyr_1.3.0            class_7.3-20           zoo_1.8-12             digest_0.6.33         
 [8] lmtest_0.9-40          utf8_1.2.3             R6_2.5.1               httr_1.4.7             pillar_1.9.0           rlang_1.1.1            lazyeval_0.2.2        
[15] curl_5.1.0             misc3d_0.9-1           rstudioapi_0.15.0      data.table_1.14.8      fracdiff_1.5-2         TTR_0.24.3             labeling_0.4.3        
[22] htmlwidgets_1.6.2      munsell_0.5.0          proxy_0.4-27           compiler_4.1.2         xfun_0.40              pkgconfig_2.0.3        base64enc_0.1-3       
[29] forecast_8.21.1        urca_1.3-3             htmltools_0.5.6.1      tcltk_4.1.2            nnet_7.3-17            tidyselect_1.2.0       tibble_3.2.1          
[36] quadprog_1.5-8         dtw_1.23-1             fansi_1.0.5            viridisLite_0.4.2      dplyr_1.1.3            withr_2.5.1            grid_4.1.2            
[43] nlme_3.1-155           jsonlite_1.8.7         gtable_0.3.4           lifecycle_1.0.3        magrittr_2.0.3         scales_1.2.1           KernSmooth_2.23-20    
[50] quantmod_0.4.25        cli_3.6.1              longitudinalData_2.4.5 tseries_0.10-54        timeDate_4022.108      ellipsis_0.3.2         xts_0.13.1            
[57] generics_0.1.3         vctrs_0.6.4            tools_4.1.2            glue_1.6.2             purrr_1.0.2            clv_0.3-2.4            maps_3.4.1.1          
[64] crosstalk_1.2.0        parallel_4.1.2         fastmap_1.1.1          yaml_2.3.7             colorspace_2.1-0       locpol_0.8.0           knitr_1.44
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing out the warnings first? You can clear up one at least by moving `text  = ...` to `ggplot(aes(`  from `geom_point(aes(` Another suggestion if these are examples ... it might be better to use `require()` instead of `library()` (the former warns, the latter errors). It's really difficult to help when it isn't reproducible...I also realize that it would be really difficult to make this type of problem reproducible. Let me know if these suggestions do *nothing* or create a new problem.

Comment: I have found that loading package TSclut is the problem, see my edited report.